# Formats for Saving Vector-based 3D Graphics

Tags: file-format, vector-graphics

I have written a vector-based 3D editor (UI customized somewhat like technical drawings). I now want save the vectors/drawing data in portable formats. Which formats are available; which (one?) of them are the most widely accepted, and where can I get hold of the format specifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commercially, many users will look for AutoCAD DWG and Bentley DGN formats.  While not free, libraries for producing these formats can be found from [the open design alliance](http://www.opendwg.org/home)

The GIS community use [shape files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) quite a bit for vectorised 3d models, a free SDK for shape files can be found [here](http://shapelib.maptools.org/).  The [OSG library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSceneGraph) is also free and supports a number of vector graphics formats.

Answer (score 1):

[Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/)

Comment: I saw that; It says two-dimensional... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

DXF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD_DXF

Comment: DXF has been around for quite a while now and is a widely accepted interchange format. There are, however, different versions which cope with different types of entities.