# Visualizing, in 3D, points, lines and triangles (C++ API and file format)

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

How do people visualize, in 3D, points, lines and triangles (not just triangles) that result from C++ code?

- Is there a lightweight C++ API?
- Is there a combination of a lightweight file format and a stable 3D viewer?

**OpenGL** is too low-level. Plus, I do not know how suitable OpenGL is for rendering points and lines.
**VTK** is too complex for such a simple task and is not well-documented.
**X3D** is not a lightweight file format. Plus, I have not found a viewer that convinces me. **DirectX** is not platform-independent.

I am really curious to learn what people do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such libraries are rarely done by halves. If any such library exists, I would actually be interested myself.

First off: consider exporting to any old 3D (or 2D for that matter) file format. [Check here in this case.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187921/formats-for-saving-vector-based-3d-graphics)

Otherwise you probably will want to use OpenGL as it has the most community support and it is platform-independent. Did you check out [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/OpenSceneGraph/)? OSG will take some of that low-level burden away for you.

If you're looking for lightweight, go for OpenGL directly ([glut](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) + [glew](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLEW/) are relatively simple to setup and draw some vertexbuffers with i.e. points, lines or triangles):
I find [redbook](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/redbook/) a really nice resource for beginners (OpenGL < 3.1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! glut + glew is exactly what I am using so far. In addition, I wrote code to save a 2D projection to SVG, but without solving the Visibility Problem. AFAIK, there is virtually node code that takes 3D geometry as the input and outputs a 2D projection as 2D vector graphics.

Comment: by my best guess, the geometric problem is quite difficult for abitrary geometry, while rasterisation simplifies the problem to bits - so path of least resistance?

Comment: Absolutely. But with only triangles (and no other polygons), it's not rocket science either.